# Does Blazor have a "UI thread"?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

My previous programming was Windows Forms and in that there is a UI thread and any code that touches the UI must be called in that thread. Not a major problem once you got the hang of it but you had to be careful to always call in that thread.

Does Blazor (server side) have the same concept? I'm guessing no because everything, regardless of thread, is pushing something into the circuit that then is a single thread on the client side.

But I figure better to ask. Are there any limits about what code can be called from which threads?

---

And additional follow-on question. Every call I get such as `OnInitializedAsync` is in that UI thread - correct? There's all these async events I implement, from Blazor and from DevExpress components. While they're all async, they're all in that main UI thread - correct?

Which means I only have to be concerned with this if I create a background thread or timer. (In the WinForms case you were often in the non UI thread when you got events/callbacks.)

Comment: Yes but not quite. It has a *circuit* which acts the same way. You can't have multiple threads sending conflicting UI modification commands to the same browser tab after all. In Blazor WASM each tab runs on a single thread, so the effect is the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each server side session in the Blazor Hub has the equivalent of a UI thread called a `Synchronisation Context`.  Think of it as a virtual thread.

To quote directly from this document - https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/blazor/components/synchronization-context.md

> Blazor uses a synchronization context (System.Threading.SynchronizationContext) to enforce a single logical thread of execution. A component's lifecycle methods and event callbacks raised by Blazor are executed on the synchronization context.

> Blazor Server's synchronization context attempts to emulate a single-threaded environment so that it closely matches the WebAssembly model in the browser, which is single threaded. At any given point in time, work is performed on exactly one thread, which yields the impression of a single logical thread. No two operations execute concurrently.

Given that, there's nothing stopping you offloading some processor intensive code to a threadpool thread if you want in Blazor Server.  WASM is currently single threaded so you can't offload.  Multi-threading is promised.

A notable exception are timers in Server.  They run on a threadpool thread. If your event handler calls `StateHasChanged` you need to  call `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` to switch it back to the Synchronisation Context.

The `ComponentBase` method looks like this:

```cs
protected Task InvokeAsync(Action workItem)
    => _renderHandle.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(workItem);
```

`_renderHandle.Dispatcher` is a reference to the Synchronisation Context's Dispatcher.

So, the important knowledge to take for this is:

- All Renderer generated events - `IComponent`, `IHandleEvent`, `IHandleAfterRender` and UI callback events (such as button clicks, change events) are run on the `Synchronisation Context`.
- Only one block of code is run at a time - there no parallel processing.
- Yielding back to the context allows the Renderer to service it's queues. Continuations are kicked down the road, and render and UI generated event code can be run.

Comment: Thank you and I added a follow-on part to the question above.

Comment: See the addition info in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Blazor, UI runs on a different thread while working with async tasks, you can access UI thread like this

```
Dispatcher.CreateDefault().InvokeAsync(() =>{});
```

Comment: [Polite] "In Blazor, UI runs on a different thread while working with async tasks".  Not true.  See my answer above. everything runs on the `Synchronisation Context` unless you specifically switch it to another thread.   I'm not sure how `Dispatcher.CreateDefault().InvokeAsync(() =>{});` relates to the question?

Comment: @Stephen Cleary - https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary - can either straighten me out on this or confirm?